# Collision handler detecting too early in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

I have created a 2d boolean array which detects my collision. There are four detectors on each corner of my hitbox for the player and the collision simply says if the spot on to the left is true you cant move left, and vice versa for the right side. The right side works flawlessly but the left side stops my player before he actually reaches the platform that is stopping him. Here is a picture to show what is happening(there are two other hit boxes in the ground the hitboxes are red)

[image: Collision example]

And here is the code for the collision handler

```
    public void run() {
    /*If entity can fall i.e not on a platform*/
    if(entity instanceof CollidableObject){
        /*Each line is stating that if the current position.x + 1 is true and the y coordinate is true (in grid of course) then
         * there must be something there and so stop falling
         */
        if(/*mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x)][(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y - 1)] || */
           mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + 1)][(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y)] || 
           mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + 1)][(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y)]/* || 
           mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionRight().x + 3)][(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y )]*/){
                    entity.canFall(false);
                    entity.canJump(true);
        }else{
            entity.canFall(true);
            entity.canJump(false);
            }

    }

    if(entity instanceof CollidableObject){

        /*Each line is stating that if the current position.y + 1 is true and the x coordinate is true (in grid of course) then
         * there must be something there and so stop moving right
         */
        if(mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + (int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getDimensions().x / MapGrid.TILE_SIZE))]
                   [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 1)] || 
           mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + (int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getDimensions().x / MapGrid.TILE_SIZE))]
                   [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 2)] || 
                   mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + (int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getDimensions().x / MapGrid.TILE_SIZE))]
                           [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 3)]|| 
                           mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x + (int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getDimensions().x / MapGrid.TILE_SIZE))]
                                   [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 4)]){
                    entity.canMoveRight(false);
        }else
            entity.canMoveRight(true);

        if(entity instanceof CollidableObject){
            /*Each line is stating that if the current position.x is true and the y coordinate is true (or +1 , +2 because
             * of the height of the player) then
             * there must be something there and so stop moving left
             */
            if(mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x)]
                       [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionRight().y + 1)] || 
                       mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x)]
                       [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 2)] || 
                       mapGrid.getMapGrid()[(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().x)]
                       [(int) (((CollidableObject) entity).getGridPositionLeft().y + 3)]){
                        entity.canMoveLeft(false);
            }else
                entity.canMoveLeft(true);
        }
    }
```

The overall problem is that the player won't make it left because it is checking way too soon and if it doesn't check soon the player ends up halfway through the platform so what am I doing wrong?! Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: keep on updating your sprite bounds by using sprite.getBoundingRectangle(). p.s. sprite is the refernce ot your character image. I hope u have it in sprite or atlassprite. if not change it. it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to check from the bottom right instead of bottom left when checking for left side collisions because moving left updates way faster then when moving right. This is because for the grid position to update while moving right you have to get all the way through the cell before the grid position updates(it updates when hitting the upper right side of the cell) =. Knowing this if you move left, you will immediately hit the top right section of the cell and cause an instant update. By updating from the right, it will take one cell longer to update which is exactly what is needed to get the solution.